# Converting time to Military

Tags: c#, datetime

In an attempt to turn a date with a format of `"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss PM"` into military time, the following replacement of a row value does not seem to take. Even though I am sure I have done this before (with column values other than dates). Is there some reason that `row["adate"]` would not accept a value assigned to it in this case?

```
DateTime oos = DateTime.Parse(row["adate"].ToString());

row["adate"] =  oos.Month.ToString() 
              + "/" 
              + oos.Day.ToString() 
              + "/" 
              + oos.Year.ToString() 
              + " " 
              + oos.Hour.ToString() 
              + ":" 
              + oos.Minute.ToString();
```

Comment: `row["adate"] =  oos.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm") ` might be better

Comment: @Philip Fourie: row["adate"].Text = oos.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm")  post it as an answer and get some reputation! :)

Comment: What is `row`? BTW, you can use this: `oos.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyy H:m");`

Comment: For the sake of the less educated... could you please add a half-sentence to the question that describes in technical terms what *"Military time"* is? Ugh, never mind, this question is dead old but bumped to the top because of the new answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of formatting the string manually, you should use:

```
oos.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Also, what do you mean by "would not accept a value"? Are you getting an exception? If so, what is the error message?

Answer (score 4):

Beside first answer check this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Yeah, and all the people posting their MM/dd/yyyy solutions should go their too, and have a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator and the differences between for example MM and M

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
row["adate"].Text = oos.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm");
```

Comment: YYYY has to be in lowercase. `yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

*If you have this time: 07:12:02PM and you want this: 19:12:02PM, then this is the code for you!*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution {

    static string timeConversion(string s) {
       DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "hh:mm:sstt", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

        return (dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    }

    static void Main(String[] args) {
        string s = Console.ReadLine(); 
        string result = timeConversion(s);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# >= 6.0 you can use string interpolation as well if you need to add something around your date. Something like:

```cs
row["adate"] = $"S: {StartDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is

```
bool timeConversion = DateTime.TryParse(s,out DateTime time);

if(timeConversion)
{
return time.Tostring("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

> here be careful to write "HH"