# How to convert a C# DateTime to a C# DateTime without the AM/PM and in 24 hour format?

Tags: c#

I see a ton of questions about this but they all convert to a string, which is not what I am trying to do. I need it to still be a date time object after changing it to a 24 hour format without the AM/PM. An example of a date that I want to convert is - 9/6/2017 1:00:00 PM and I want it to look like 09-06-2017 13:00:00. I have searched for this for far too long, I would think it would be easier than this.

EDIT:
I think I asked this incorrectly, how do i convert a string like - "09-06-2017 13:00:00" into a date that looks exactly the same.

As far as I can tell this is not the same as what I have seen asked in the past, or I could not find it.

Comment: You're talking about converting it to a string. A `DateTime` doesn't "have" an am/pm marker, and it has no concept 12 hour vs 24 hours; those things are part of stringifying it (or not, depending on format). *Any* `DateTime` instance can be stringified with or without am/pm, depending on what format information you pass to `dt.ToString()`, or `String.Format()`, or whatever you use to stringify it.

Comment: `DateTime` does not have a format.  Formats only come into play when converting it to a string.

Comment: A date is a date is a date. No formatting involved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417093/converting-time-to-military

Comment: `"they all convert to a string, which is not what I am trying to do"` - Yes it is.  That is *exactly* what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe I asked it wrong, how do I convert a string like - "09-06-2017 13:00:00"  to a date that looks exactly the same?

Comment: @CSchroeder look at the accepted answer of the linked duplicate, except your format will be `"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to find out what all the letters mean.

Comment: To make the round trip it would be `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("09-06-2017 13:00:00", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to get the date time object, and to get it back you do `string dtString = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 2):

```
// InvariantCulture may not be needed depending on your machine default region/language settings
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

> 9/6/2017 14:39:50

Also see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)